# struct array inside another struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to create an structure with other structures inside.

```
    struct bullet{
        char bullet_sprite[100];
        int pos_x;
        int pos_y;
        int ace_x;
        int tag;
    };


  struct bullets_onscreen{
        struct bullet v[2];
        struct bullet a[2];
  };
```

I get this error:

> error: array type has incomplete element type

Is this posible to do?

Example code:

```
//Calling functions
struct bullets_onscreen[2] //public 

struct bullet bala[1];
init_bullet(&bala,_player);
set_bullet_on_screen(&bala);

void set_bullet_on_screen(struct bullet *_bullet){
        array_bullet[1] = _bullet;
}
void init_bullet(struct bullet *_bullet, struct player *_player){
        //inits all bullet components
}
```

Comment: It is perfectly valid. What's the problem ? The error message you are getting may comes from another part of your code.

Comment: This is perfectly fine. But as as alternative, you can make `bullets_onscreen` as array of 4 `bullet` ? `struct bullet bullets_onscreen[4];`

Comment: `struct bullets_onscreen[2] //public` --> `struct bullets_onscreen[2]; //public`

Answer (score 3):

As written your code is fine. Presumably in the actual code you have reversed the order of the two struct definitions. This code produces the error you report:

```
struct bullets_onscreen{
    struct bullet v[2];
    struct bullet a[2];
};

struct bullet{
    char bullet_sprite[100];
    int pos_x;
    int pos_y;
    int ace_x;
    int tag;
};
```

Define the structs in the order that you did in the question and your code will compile.

Comment: I don't think so. Show an SSCCE.